# OrientDB import edges only using ETL tool

Tags: etl, orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb-etl

I already used the OETL to insert all my Vertex to the graph.

Now I have a file that outlines the edges at the following way:

> node_1,rel_type,node_2
>   11000001,relation_A,10208879
>   11000001,relation_A,10198662
>   11000001,relation_B,10159927
>   11000001,relation_C,10165779

How can I import it using the OrientDB OETL tool?

I tried the following:

```
"transformers": [
    { "csv": {} },
    { "command" : {
            "command" : "create edge ${rel_type} from (select flatten(@rid) from V where node_id= ${node_1}) to (select flatten(@rid) from V where node_id = ${node_2})",
            "output" : "edge"
        }
    }
  ],
```

But this failed to work since it can't parse the values from the csv.

Comment: How did you import all of the vertexes ? using the normal import tool  found on orientdb documentation ? because I'm facing the same problem now

Answer (score 1):

You must use the $input variable.

```
"transformers": [{
        "csv": {
            "separator": ","
        }
    },
    {
    "command" : {
            "command" : "create edge ${input.rel_type} from (select from V where node_id= ${input.node_1}) to (select from V where node_id = ${input.node_2})",
            "output" : "edge"
        }
    }
  ],
```

It works for me.

[image]

Hope it helps.