# How to import Edges from CSV with ETL into OrientDB graph?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-etl

I'm trying to import edges from a CSV-file into OrientDB. The vertices are stored in a separate file and already imported via ETL into OrientDB.
So my situation is similar to [OrientDB import edges only using ETL tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133409/orientdb-import-edges-only-using-etl-tool) and [OrientDB ETL loading CSV with vertices in one file and edges in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628356/orientdb-etl-loading-csv-with-vertices-in-one-file-and-edges-in-another).

---

**Update**

Friend.csv

```
"id","client_id","first_name","last_name"
"0","0","John-0","Doe"
"1","1","John-1","Doe"
"2","2","John-2","Doe"
...
```

The `"id"` field is removed by the Friend-Importer, but the `"client_id"` is stored. The idea is to have a known client-side generated `id` for searching etc.

PeindingFriendship.csv

```
"friendship_id","client_id","from","to"
"0","0-1","1","0"
"2","0-15","15","0"
"3","0-16","16","0"
...
```

The `"friendship_id"` and `"client_id"` should be imported as attributes of the `"PendingFriendship"` edge. `"from"` is a `"client_id"` of a Friend. `"to"` is a `"client_id"` of another Friend.
For `"client_id"` exists a unique Index on both `Friend` and `PendingFriendship`.

---

My ETL configuration looks like this

```
...
"extractor": {
  "csv": {
  }
},
"transformers": [
  {
    "command": {
      "command": "CREATE EDGE PendingFriendship FROM (SELECT FROM Friend WHERE client_id = '${input.from}') TO (SELECT FROM Friend WHERE client_id = '${input.to}') SET client_id = '${input.client_id}'",
      "output": "edge"
    }
  },
  {
    "field": {
      "fieldName": "from",
      "expression": "remove"
    }
  },
  {
    "field": {
      "fieldName": "to",
      "operation": "remove"
    }
  },
  {
    "field": {
      "fieldName": "friendship_id",
      "expression": "remove"
    }
  },
  {
    "field": {
      "fieldName": "client_id",
      "operation": "remove"
    }
  },
  {
    "field": {
      "fieldName": "@class",
      "value": "PendingFriendship"
    }
  }
],
...
```

The issue with this configuration is that it creates two edge entries. One is the expected "PendingFriendship" edge. The second one is an empty "PendingFriendship" edge, with all the fields I removed as attributes with empty values.
The import fails, at the second row/document, because another empty "PendingFriendship" cannot be inserted because it violates a uniqueness constraint.
How can I avoid the creation of the unnecessary empty "PendingFriendship".
What is the best way to import edges into OrientDB? All the examples in the documentation use CSV files where vertices and edges are in one file, but this is not the case for me.

I also had a look into the [Edge-Transformer](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Transformer.html#edge-transformer), but it returns a Vertex not an Edge!

[Created PendingFriendships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCABJ.png)

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: I'm running OrientDB inside Docker. I'm using the Version 2.2.24 from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb/).
I had the same behavior with version 2.2.22.

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi do you have any idea how the import can be fixed? As mentioned above the used version is 2.2.24.
Thx.

Comment: Cna you provide the csv file? Thx

Comment: ok, thank you let me see if I understood well, the Friend.csv is already imported and you have to import the PeindingFriendship.csv but you have problems, am I right?

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi yes, you are right.

Comment: ok, one more thing, can you post the entire json file? Thx in advance

Comment: No, it has 100000 lines. But the ids exist in both files. I imported the same CSV files to MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found a way (workaround) to import the above data into OrientDB. Instead of using the [ETL Tool](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/ETL-Introduction.html) I wrote simple ruby scripts which call the HTTP API of OrientDB using the [Batch](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/OrientDB-REST.html#batch) endpoint.

Steps:

1. Import the Friends.
2. Use the response to create a mapping of `client_ids` to `@rids`.
3. Parse the `PeindingFriendship.csv` and build `batch` requests.
4. Each Friendships is created by its own command.
5. The mapping from 2. is used to insert the `@rids` into the command from 4.
6. Send the `batch` requests in junks of 1000 commands.

Example Batch-Request body:

```
{
  "transaction" : true,
  "operations" : [
    {
      "type" : "cmd",
      "language" : "sql",
      "command" : "create edge PendingFriendship from #27:178 to #27:179 set client_id='4711'"
    }
  ]
}
```

This isn't the answer to the question I asked, but it solves the higher goal of importing data into OrientDB, for me. Therefore I leave it open for the community to mark this question as solved or not.